# Need a metaphor - "Your problem will disappear like smoke in air "

Tags: metaphors

> Your problem will disappear like smoke in air.

Is this an appropriate metaphor?

Comment: *Is this an appropriate metaphor?* How can we possibly answer that without more context?  For example, *Just lost your leg in a motorcycle accident and worrying about bleeding to death?  Think positively and your problem will disappear like smoke in air* no, not appropriate.

Comment: In this age of concern over global warming, this may remind the reader more of pollution than disappearance.

Comment: If the problems hang around a long time, making people cough, then sure.

Comment: "... disappeared like a rat up a drainpipe"

Comment: When you use the word "like" in an expression it's called a similie, not a metaphor.  You could easily turn it into a metaphor however, perhaps something like  "Your problem is merely smoke in the wind".

Answer (score 2):

In English it would be more common to refer to the wind, rather than the air, in the context of dispersing. I feel like metaphors about the air are more likely to refer to something floating or lingering for example if things are 'up in the air', or there is 'trouble in the air'. To me, saying 'disappear like smoke in the wind' would sound much more natural than 'disappear like smoke in the air'.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google "disappear like" you'll find people often invent their own similes. Perhaps you could do that. Or use one of theirs.

In the UK things routinely *vanish* into [thin air](https://www.lexico.com/definition/thin_air).

Only when they are *burnt* do they [go up in smoke](https://www.lexico.com/definition/go_up_in_smoke).

As High Performance Mark said, we don't know what might be appropriate because you haven't told us the context.

Answer (score 0):

Hosea 13:3 [GNT] certainly uses this metaphor (better phrased) in simile format (among others):

> *... will disappear like morning mist,*
> *like the dew that vanishes early in the day.*
> *They will be like chaff which the wind blows from the threshing place,*
> *like smoke from a chimney.*

[[BibleGateway.com](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Hosea%2013%3A3)]But without knowing the tenor, as others have said, one can't judge the appropriateness of the vehicle of a metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the word "like" or "as" in an expression it's called a similie, not a metaphor.

You could easily turn it into a metaphor however, if you want to be creative. Perhaps something like this

> Your problem is merely smoke in the wind.

Or for fun, I could imagine Shakespeare saying something like

> 'Tis nothing but a fart in the wind.

I think it's better to use "the wind" here because a fart in the air would just linger, and there's a play on words here too. Sometimes people refer to a fart as "wind", as a euphemism.